# Why is `this` in nested function the window object when I set the context with the `.call` method?

Tags: javascript, this, currying, lexical-scope

I do not understand why the `this` value is the `window` object when I set the context for the `f6` function to run with the object `obj`.

```js
let obj = {
  color: "blue",
  name: "maya"
};

function f6() {
  return function() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}

f6.call(obj)();
```

Comment: The `this` in `function() { console.log(this); }` is distinct from the one in `f6` (and `this` isn’t used in the scope of `f6`). Use an arrow function instead: `function f6(){ return () => console.log(this); }`.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that an arrow function would fix this issue. But I dont quite understand why the this in the return function would be different than the this in f6. Why is that?

Comment: Every `function`, method, and `class` creates its own `this` binding scope. You’re not calling the returned function with any _this_ binding (you only do that with `f6`), so it’s `globalThis`.

Comment: Related: [How does the “this” keyword work?](/q/3127429/4642212).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 0):

In `function` functions, `this` is not determined by lexical scope.
It’s determined by how the function is called, and in what context.
Each `function` function creates its own `this` binding environment.

```js
function f(){
  this;          // This `this` is distinct …
  
  function g(){
    this;        // … from this `this`.
  }
}
```

```js
function f(){
  console.log(this);
}

const objX = {
    f
  },
  objY = {};

objX.f();      // Logs `objX`, because the expression `objX.f` is a member of a reference.
f();           // No `this` binding. `f` by itself isn’t the member of a reference.
f.call(objY);  // Logs `objY`, because `this` was explicitly set.
```

Arrow functions, on the other hand, get the `this` binding from their lexical scope.
Arrow functions do not create their own `this` binding environment.

```js
function f(){
  this;          // This `this` is the same …
  
  () => {
    this;        // … as this `this`.
  };
}
```

You’re calling `f6` with `.call` to provide a `this` binding.
That’s where the `f6` function gets its `this` value from, but `f6` *doesn’t use* its `this` value.

Unrelatedly, `f6` returns a function that happens to use `this`.
Again, it’s a `function` function, so its `this` binding depends on the call.
If you’re wondering what the *returned function’s* `this` value will be, you’ll have to examine the call:

```js
f6.call(obj)();

// Equivalent to:
   (f6.call(obj)) ();
// -^^^^^^^^^^^^-      Returned function.
//                ^^   Call.
```

`.call` or `.apply` isn’t used on the returned function, and `.bind` wasn’t used, so the `this` binding isn’t set explicitly.
`(f6.call(obj))` also isn’t an expression with a member of a reference (i.e. a *[MemberExpression](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-MemberExpression)*).
The call was performed without providing a context, so the context will be `globalThis`, or `undefined` in strict mode.

Using an arrow function resolves this:

```js
function f6(){
  return () => console.log(this);
}

f6.call(obj)(); // Logs `obj`.
```

Alternatively, using `.bind` in the return would also resolve this:

```js
function f6(){
  return function(){
    console.log(this);
  }.bind(this);
}

f6.call(obj)(); // Logs `obj`.
```

And of course, using something that *is* lexically scoped<sup>1</sup>, i.e. variables, would also resolve this:

```js
function f6(){
  const that = this;
  
  return function(){
    console.log(that);
  };
}

f6.call(obj)(); // Logs `obj`.
```

---

<sup>1</sup>: I guess you could say that `this` is also lexically scoped, but is overshadowed by each nested `function` function.

---

See also:

- [ECMAScript specification on function calls](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function-calls)
- [ECMAScript specification on the `this` keyword](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-this-keyword)
- [Stack Overflow: How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/4642212)

Comment: Thank you very much Sebastian. So it seems like the "this" isn't inherited by the parent function which I initially presumed. I forgot to consider how it was called. It was very helpful to see it like this: (f6.call(obj))() since this shows where I am calling it from which is just the "window" object: window.(f6.call(obj))(). Thanks again, Sebastian.